# How can I show an dialog in which the permissions of a registry key can be set

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, dialog, registry

I'm working on a registry editor for Windows.

I want to add an dialog which can be used to change the permissions for a specific registry key. This is the way it should look like:

[image: The change permissions dialog]

This dialog is used by regedit and also by third party registry editing software such as 
O&O Regeditor.
I'm looking for a windows function which displays such a dialog. I already did a search on MSDN but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the [Access Control Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374865%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).